# FFMPEG api convertion file error

Tags: ffmpeg, converters

I'm trying to convert video thanks to the API [(using the transcoding example)](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/transcoding_8c-example.html) which I adapted a very few (like 5 lines) and force the codec to `MJPEG`. It encode 3 or 4 frames then it quit saying `Invalid pts (3) <= last (3)`. Here's the whole trace :

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/thomas/test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2014-09-05 15:42:24
  Duration: 00:00:29.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 943 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 935 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 6k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-05 15:42:24
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-05 15:42:24
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Output #0, mov, to '/Users/thomas/test_MJPEG.mov':
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
[mov @ 0x7ffd6202e600] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
[mov @ 0x7ffd6202e600] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
[swscaler @ 0x7ffd6204d000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Pushing decoded frame to filters
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Encoding frame
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Pushing decoded frame to filters
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Encoding frame
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Pushing decoded frame to filters
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Encoding frame
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Pushing decoded frame to filters
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Encoding frame
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Pushing decoded frame to filters
Pulling filtered frame from filters
Encoding frame
[mjpeg @ 0x7ffd6202ec00] Invalid pts (3) <= last (3)
Error occurred: Operation not permitted
```

I don't know how to fix this, am I using invalid settings ?

[Here's the movie I'm working with](http://cplusnet.fr/test.mov)

FYI, I'd like to achieve the same thing than the command `ffmpeg -i test.mov -vcodec mjpeg testMJPEG.mov`